# Show that $(x_n)$ is decreasing and find its limit.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

Let $0<x_1<1$. For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $x_{n+1}=1- \sqrt{1-x_n}$. Show that $(x_n)$ is decreasing and find its limit.

I did:
$$x_{n+1} = 1- \sqrt{1-x_n}$$
$$x_{n+1} - x_n= 1- \sqrt{1-x_n} - x_n$$
We know that 
$$\sqrt{1-x_n}<1-x_n$$
and so,
$$x_{n+1} - x_n< 1- (1-x_n) - x_n< 1- 1+x_n- x_n<0$$
Therefore, $$x_{n+1} < x_n$$
Thus, $(x_n)$ is decreasing

How can I keep going to find the limit?

Comment: The limit $L$ has to satisfy $L = 1 - \sqrt{1 - L}$; do you see why?

Comment: @T.Bongers yes!!! so $L =0$, and $L=1$

Comment: ${\large x_{n} \to 0}$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$

1. $\ds{\color{#0000ff}{\large x_{n + 1}} = 1 - \root{1 - x_{n}} = {x_{n} \over 1 + \root{1 - x_{n}}}
            \color{#0000ff}{\large < x_{n}}}$
2. $\ds{\phi_{n} \equiv \root{1 - x_{n}}\quad\imp\quad \phi_{n + 1}
            = \phi_{n}^{1/2}}$:
       $$
       \phi_{n} = \phi_{n - 1}^{1/2} = \phi_{n - 2}^{1/4} = \phi_{n - 3}^{1/8}
       = \cdots = \phi_{1}^{1/2^{n - 1}}
       \quad\imp\quad\lim_{n \to \infty}\phi_{n} = 1
       $$
       Then, $\ds{\color{#0000ff}{\large\lim_{n \to \infty}x_{n} = 0}}$

Comment: Could you explain what you did?

Comment: @OrchidFibio I explained two points you asked: 1) $x_{n + 1} < x_{n}$ (just multiply num... and den... by $1 + \sqrt{1 - x_{n}}$). It is obvious that the new den... is $> 1$. In 2) there is a redefinition which let's to iterate easily. Once we find the $\phi_{n}$ limit, we can infer the $x_{n}$ limit since $x_{n} = 1 - \phi_{n}^{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

First notice that if $x_n\gt0$, then $\sqrt{1-x_n}\lt1$, so $x_{n+1}=1-\sqrt{1-x_n}\gt0$. Furthermore,
$$
\begin{align}
x_{n+1}
&=1-\sqrt{1-x_n}\\
&=\frac{x_n}{1+\sqrt{1-x_n}}\\
&\lt x_n
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, $x_n$ is decreasing and bounded below. Thus, $x_\infty=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n$ exists and
$$
\begin{align}
x_\infty=1-\sqrt{1-x_\infty}
&\implies x_\infty(2-x_\infty)=x_\infty\\
&\implies x_\infty^2-x_\infty=0
\end{align}
$$
Since $x_\infty<1$, we must have $x_\infty=0$.

Answer (score 1):

See $\{x_n\}$ is monotone decreasing and bounded below. Zero is a lower bound. So it is convergent and $L = \lim x_n$. As T. Bongers has written in his comment the limit should satisfy $L = 1 - \sqrt{1 - L}$

Comment: and then $L=0$ and $L=1$, right?